# Will birds in my loft affect me selling my house?

Tags: attic

I hope this is the correct S.E for this question, if not, please direct me to the best one.

I have got birds in my loft, I went up and saw one earlier today. Normally, that isn't a problem, I would wait until it moves on, then go ahead and block up the place they got in. However, I am in the process of selling my house. It is on the market and has had interest already. I know if we sell it, a survey will have to be done. If they find the bird in the loft, will they fail the survey and make the sale fall through? As far as I know, I am not allowed to actually get rid of the bird until it moves, at any rate, I am unsure of the species.

If it helps, I am in the UK

Comment: When buying a home I would consider animal intrusion into the attic a problem.

Comment: Yeah, in aware it's a problem, but it can be solved. The question is will this cause a failure in the survey and stop the house being able to be sold?

Comment: i would say that it depends entirely on the buyer

Comment: So the answer is no? It wont affect the survey? I'm not asking if the buyer will be affected. That's not an answerable question. I'm asking about the survey that needs to be done as part of the selling process. Will it fail the survey? That's the question

Comment: i am not in UK, so it is unclear why the survey would have precedence over the buyer's decision .... where I am the survey is a declaration of problems found and it is up to the buyer to decide what to do with the information